# Cannot open/include (file)

Tags: c++, graphics, visual-studio-2017, sfml

I am trying to use a graphics library (SFML) for c++, and I am having issues. I use Visual Studio 2017. I have watched many Youtube tutorials, and get the same error with every one I try. I can't find the solution, as people are saying "the folders need to be together" which I have already done:
[image]
Here are the errors I get:

> E1696
>   cannot open source file "stdafx.h" c:\Users\George\source\repos\Game\Game\main.cpp 1
>
> E0065
>   expected a ';'
>   c:\Users\George\source\repos\Game\Game\main.cpp 5
>
> E1696
>   cannot open source file "SFML/Graphics.hpp" c:\Users\George\source\repos\Game\Game\main.cpp 2
>
> C1083
>   Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory c:\users\george\source\repos\game\game\main.cpp 1

The code I am running (copied, with extra):

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Before, the code did not have the stdafx.h or namespace std so I had to add them because I had other errors. I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: *"Before, the code did not have the stdafx.h or namespace std so I had to add them because I had other errors."* -- You should have asked about those errors instead.

Comment: Best advice I can give is to pick up a book from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and *read* it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yeah but stdafx is required in VS 2017?

Comment: @George_E: No. It is not.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I took it away and get "Can't open source file: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' "

Comment: @George_E: Like I said. You should have asked about those original errors.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I don't want to write it out all again though ):

Comment: @BenjaminLindley If I get rid of namespace std as well I get: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0276 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name Game c:\Users\George\source\repos\Game\Game\main.cpp 7

Comment: Don't follow random Youtube tutorials. [This](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php) is the official tutorial. It's text, because you will need to have it side-by-side with your screen and you will need to do what it says *at your speed*, not at the speed of some random youtube guy. Please follow it *to the letter* and you will be able to get this running.

Comment: @nvoigt Forgot to post answer to my own question, but now I have. I figured out that I had it say the wrong type of system

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out a few days ago, but forgot to post how I fixed it. I downloaded the 32-bit version of SFML. In properties, you need to make sure it says: "Active(win32)" or something like that. I had mine on "x64" which is why it didn't work. Hope this helped someone else with the same problem :)